Magento 2 | Default shipping address not selected after shipping methods reload
Version: 2.4.6-p6
After accessing checkout shipping step, after page is loaded, my default shipping address is preselected which is fine.
Right after that, shipping methods are gets reloaded (loader is shown) and my default shipping address became not selected, so basically after that reload none of shipping addresses is selected and customer has to do it again.
If I reload the page again then it will remain pre-selected because there is no anymore that additional reload of shipping methods.

does reloading of the shipping addresses occurs after you change any of the shipping address fields? If yes than this occurs , since you are changing the shipping address and now magento has to re fetch the estimated shipping methods for newly entered shipping address.
